# How to apply formulas in rows with unknown no of columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This works:

[image]

This does not:

[image]

I don't know why.

EDIT:

Thanks to Marios this works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(B5:5 = "Start","",IF(
    B6:6-A6:6>-1,B6:6-A6:6,0)))
```

"Start" to be changed to a named range with the actual date at the top of the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are trying to execute this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(C6:6-B6:6)`

in cell `C7`.

The issue with that is this part `B6:6`. This is a range of columns starting from `B` until the last column in your sheet, but since you put that formula in cell `C7` your starting point is column `C`.

Essentially, you want to put the range of values from column `B` until the last column of the sheet but your available space is from `C` until the last column of the sheet and therefore you lack **1 column** as the error also suggests.

An analogy would be:
fit a big box inside of a smaller one with a size difference of one column. In this case the big box is the range of `B6:6` and you are trying to put it in a smaller box of a range `C6:6`.

### Solution:

Try to put that formula on cell `B7` and it will work. Don't drag it, because the big range will shift to column `A` and you will face the same issue. Just use the same exact formula on cell `B7`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(C6:6-B6:6)`

While this might not be your goal, it explains what is the current issue you are facing and what to do in order to fix it.

Update based on your solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(IF(B5:5 = "Start","",IF(B6:6-A6:6>-1,B6:6-A6:6,0)),""))
```

I added an `iferror` check to catch the first error value caused by the string.

Comment: I put a solution in the original. If you can improve it saves embarrassment of me providing the answer, depriving you the tick you deserve for pointing out the rationality

Comment: @ChrisGlasier Thanks for the feedback. The only thing I can think of is that you can use iferror to catch the first value: `=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(IF(B5:5 = "Start","",IF(B6:6-A6:6>-1,B6:6-A6:6,0)),""))` . Let me know if this is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:5 = "Start","",IF(B6:6-A6:6>-1,B6:6-A6:6,0)))
```

Comment: it looks to me identical to the OP's solution.